# VMware ESXi 6.0 - How can I pass-through (add) my Mac Pro's optical drive to a VM (running OS X Mountain Lion)?

Tags: vmware, osx-mountain-lion, esxi, optical-drive, mac-pro

Bit unconventional I know, but I am running VMware ESXi 6.0 on my old Mac Pro 1.1. If you don't know what that is then (no offense, but) you won't be able to help me. The Mac Pro host has a "super drive" as its optical drive for CDs & DVDs.

I am trying to use VM pass-through to get my physical optical drive passed-through to the virtual machine. However, I have added the device to the VM and enabled pass-through, but still do not see it in the VM. What could I be doing wrong here? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Why is the Device Mode set to "Emulate CD-ROM" and not to "Passthrough CD-ROM"?

Comment: The "device mode" setting is inherited by the parent setting for "CD/DVD drive 1" - in my case I'm using "Host Device" to try and use the physical optical drive on the Mac Pro and "pass" it through to the VM (hence "emulated"). So, to answer your question, the setting is already correct and actually cannot be changed.

Comment: The manual is a real mess. It first says "If you are adding a CD/DVD drive that is backed by USB CD/DVD drive on the host, you must add the drive
as a SCSI device", then goes ahead with exactly the same procedure as you did using IDE. I even saw testimonies of users who just gave up and converted their CD to ISO, because ISO always works. Try SCSI, just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved now. I changed the "Virtual Device Node" setting (under CD/DVD 1) from IDE(0:1) to IDE(0:0) then used **terminal commands** to open and close the optical drive tray since the keyboard button does not work for some reason:
`drutil tray eject`
`drutil tray close`